# Addressing JSON in C# dynamically

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, expandoobject

I wish to write some C# which allows the client to provide a JSON string and query string. The query string would then be used to address values in the JSON object.

For example, if I had this JSON:

```
{
  "head": "big",
  "fingers": [
    "one", "thumb",
    "two", "ring"
  ],
  "arm": {
    "elbow", "locked"
  }
}
```

And this query string:

```
"fingers.two"
```

I would want to return the value `"ring"`.

Is this (or something like it) possible in C#?

I have tried using the `ExpandoObject` class, but this does not allow dynamic *runtime* inspection:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonStr);
```

As far as I can tell, the discovery of values on the `json` variable needs to be done at code time, rather than runtime, which means I cannot dynamically find values being queried for.

Comment: Maybe this has the answer you need:
[Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: Have you considered JSON queries using JSONPath etc? There's a tool here that uses those technologies http://www.jsonquerytool.com/ (JSONPath is built into JSON.Net - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)

Comment: @catalin I don't think so because I want to specify the value to be retrieved as a string, rather than code.

Comment: @charleh Thank you - I had forgotten about that class. :) Would you like to post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONPath does this

Assuming the following JSON (fixed a few syntax errors in the original)

```
{
  "head": "big",
  "fingers": {
    "one":"thumb",
    "two":"ring"
  },
  "arm": {
    "elbow": "locked"
  }
}
```

And this query

`MyJObjectOrToken.SelectToken("fingers.two")`

You will get the following output:

```
[
    "ring"
]
```

It should be trivial then to extract the value as a string using JSON.Net methods and return the result to your user.

Support for JSONPath is built into JSON.Net

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm